# Java code to insert new elements to inner child nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML document as given below.

```
<rootElement>
    <fisrtElement>
        <firstElementChild>
            <child1>A</child1>
            <child2>B</child2>
        </firstElementChild>
    </fisrtElement>
</rootElement>
```

Now I need to add a child node, `<child3>C</child3>`, into this XML document so that my final XML document will look like below.

```
<rootElement>
    <fisrtElement>
        <firstElementChild>
            <child1>A</child1>
            <child2>B</child2>
            <child3>C</child3>
        </firstElementChild>
    </fisrtElement>
</rootElement>
```

I need a Java code for this. I have searched google and now I know how to add elements to root element using `DocumentBuilderFactory`. But I don't how to do it for inner nodes as I given above. Please advice.

**Edit**

I have tried the below snippent for adding new element.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("./sample.xml"));

Element itemNode = doc.createElement("child3");
itemNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("C"));
Node channelNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel").item(0);
channelNode.appendChild(itemNode);
```

And the output is something like below.

```
<rootElement>
    <fisrtElement>
        <firstElementChild>
            <child1>A</child1>
            <child2>B</child2>
            <child3>c</child3>
        </firstElementChild>
    </fisrtElement>
</rootElement>
```

and when I ran the code again with the modification given below,

```
Element itemNode = doc.createElement("child4");
itemNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("D"));
```

The third child node `<child3>C</child3>` is getting replaced with the fourth child `<child4>D</child4>`. What I need is incrementally adding child nodes for `<firstElementChild>`. What I am missing here. Please give an advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this method on your `firstElementChild` node :

- `appendChild` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild(org.w3c.dom.Node)

Comment: The snippet worked. Unfortunately I was not writing the new element into the file, instead it was just printing on the terminal console. Sorry for the confusion. :)